# Pulling data from MySQL based on a date range

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a system where I will need to pull data from different date ranges from my MySql database.  Currently, I have a select dropdown that is dynamically populated from an array.  What I want to achieve "cleanly" is when a user clicks on a month, it populates a tables with the given data in that specific month.  While I actually achieved this, It requires a Query to be executed for each month selected.  I would like to know if there is a cleaner way of going about this.  I have done some research on the matter, but as I am new to PHP and only really in procedural now and not much OOP, I haven't found much additional info and would like some input.  Here is my code so far.  Thanks everyone for the help.  Let me know if there is additional info needed.

This is also going to get changed over to prepared statements as well.

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <select name='months' >
            <option value='default'>Select a month</option>
      <?php
          $months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October","November", "December");

          foreach($months as $currentMonth) {
             ?> 
             <option value=<?php echo $currentMonth; ?>><?php echo $currentMonth; ?></option>;
             <?php 
          }

        ?>

        </select>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" name="submitMonth">submit</button>
    </form>


    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sales Rep</th>
                <th>Rep ID</th>
                <th>Business Name</th>
                <th>Package</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Date Submitted</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

     <?php   

        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        if(isset($_POST['submitMonth'])) {
            if($_POST['months'] == 'January') {

         $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM table
                  WHERE MONTH(date) = 1 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) && user_id = $user_id";
                  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            }

        if($_POST['months'] == 'February') {

            $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM table
                  WHERE MONTH(date) = 2 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) && user_id = $user_id";
                  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            }

        }


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $referalBus= $row['business'];
        $repId = $row['id'];
        $package = $row['pack'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        $date = $row['date'];

         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>$repId</td>";
            echo "<td>$referalBus</td>";
            echo "<td>$package</td>";
             echo "<td>$status</td>";
              echo "<td>$date</td>";

        }
      } 
    }

    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can not change database structure, I will apply each month a number value in each option

```
 for(var $i=0; $i<=$months.length; $i++ ) {
 ?> 
       <option value=<? echo '$i+1' ?>><?php echo $months[$i]; ?></option>;
 <?php 
 }
?>
```

and then simply query look like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date) = ". $_POST['months'] ." AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) && user_id = $user_id";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

}

Comment: I am going to give this a try shortly and see if I can get something like this to work.  You mentioned assuming the database structure can not be changed.  It's possible that it could be. I would prefer not to, but it's possible.  Was there a suggestion for it?

Comment: I did get this to work, but I had to adjust the code a bit.  It looked like there was some javascript in here and I just adjusted it all to PHP.   for($i=0; $i <= count($months); $i++ ) {
         ?> 
               <option value=<? echo $i ?>><?php echo $months[$i]; ?></option>;
               
               
         <?php 
        
         }
        ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to use the parameter directly:

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M') = ".$_POST['months']." AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) && user_id = $user_id";
```

Comment: Note that written this way, the query cannot use an index (plus it's open to injection)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to manually create an IF statement for every month. You can just use the DATE_FORMAT() function of Mysql.

```html
 if(isset($_POST['submitMonth'])) {
          $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM table
                  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%M")  = '".$_POST['months']."' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) && user_id = $user_id";
                  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest dynamically building your query's conditions list; something like (pseudo code):

```
query = "blah blah WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(`date`) IN ("
for each month
   query.append("month's number") //Actually, need some "when to comma" logic here too
query.append(")");
```

My acquaintance with php is pretty much limited to what I see people post here; but I think there might even be some "explode" method you can use in place of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got something figured out and it worked.  Thanks for all of the feedback guys.  Here is the code that worked with prepared statement as well.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
                    <select name='months' >
                        <option value='default'>Select a month</option>

                  <?php

                      $months = array("", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October","November", "December");

                         for($i=0; $i <= count($months); $i++ ) {
                         ?> 
                               <option value=<? echo $i ?>><?php echo $months[$i]; ?></option>;

                         <?php 

                         }
                        ?>

                       </select>
                      <button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" name="submitMonth">submit</button>

                </form> 

                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sales Rep</th>
                             <th>Rep ID</th>
                              <th>Business Name</th>
                               <th>Package</th>
                               <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Date Submitted</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>

                 <?php   

                    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

                    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

                   if(isset($_POST['submitMonth'])) {

                      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT id, name, business, phone, email, status, id, date, package
                                                            FROM table
                                                            WHERE MONTH(date) = ". $_POST['months'] ." AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) && user_id = ?");
                      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_id);
                      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $name, $business, $phone, $email, $status, $id, $date, $package);
                      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td>$id</td>";
                        echo "<td>$business</td>";
                        echo "<td>$package</td>";
                         echo "<td>$status</td>";
                          echo "<td>$date</td>";

                      }
                    } 
                   }
                 }

                  ?>
                    </table>
```